# iOS Native Sign In With Apple token return bundle ID as audience instead of Service ID

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

We have a native iOS app that we're trying to add Sign In With Apple to. Everything I can find says we need to use the Service ID as the client_id. The problem is that when we implement the iOS part as in several articles out there (I'll reference some at the end of the post) it seems to use the Bundle ID as the client_id. At least that's what is in the "aud" field in the token we get. Then when we try and validate the token it fails because the validation is expecting the Service ID. Is there a way to tell it to use the Service ID or do I have to change my validation code to use the Bundle ID?

I've also setup a Javascript test Sign In With Apple page that uses the Service ID as the client_id and everything works as expected. Here's the code for that as a reference:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
    <div id="appleid-signin" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign in"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        AppleID.auth.init({
            clientId: 'com.myproject.serviceid',
            scope: 'name email',
            redirectURI: 'http://local.test:32775/signin-apple',
            state: 'Some stuff'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

References:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple
- https://fluffy.es/sign-in-with-apple-tutorial-ios/
- https://developerinsider.co/ios-13-how-to-integrate-sign-in-with-apple-in-your-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Sign in with Apple on iOS, it will always return the bundle ID of the application (from my experience) in the "aud" field, you will have to change your validation code.

You could write another API route in your backend for iOS app, so that if the request comes from that route, its audience will be bundle ID and do different validation.

Hope this helps!